# PHP PostgreSQL playlist position

Tags: php, postgresql, position, playlist

I have an issue with playlist saved in PostgreSQL.

I've got playlist for music saved in database, and it is read to table with PHP.
I used ORDER BY function in php to sort positions from database.
I would like to add a button to change the position of each file in table and database but i have no clue how to do it.

Whole code right now is:

```
<?php

    include  ('baza.php'); 

    include  ('head.php');

    include  ('funkcje2.php');

    $komunikat=null;

    $edytuj= $_GET['edytuj'];

    $typ= $_GET['typ'];

  // usuwamy piosenke z playlity 

 if (isset($_GET['usun_zplaylisty']) ) { 

        $usun_zplaylisty= $_GET['usun_zplaylisty'];  
}
 if(isset($usun_zplaylisty)) {

        $q = "DELETE FROM zasobyplaylisty WHERE id='$usun_zplaylisty'";

        $wynik =  pg_query($q) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne :".$q);

            if($wynik) $komunikat =  '<div style="color:green">Zasób został usuniety</div>';

            else $komunikat = "Błąd nie udało się usunąć zasobu";
}
            include ('menu_video.php');

                    include  ('menu.php');             


if($_REQUEST['action'] == "plus") {
    pg_query($con, "update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['prevrank'] . "where id=" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "; update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['currank'] . "where    id=" . $_REQUEST['previd']);
}

if($_REQUEST['action'] == "minus") {
    pg_query($con, "update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['nextrank'] .     "where id=" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "; update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['currank'] . "where    id=" . $_REQUEST['nextid']);
}


$q = " SELECT z.id, id_playlisty, id_melodii, ilosc_odtworzen, ostatnio_grana, nazwa, rozmiar, czas, pozycja from zasobyplaylisty z LEFT JOIN melodie m ON z.id_melodii=m.id WHERE id_playlisty=$edytuj ORDER BY pozycja";

$wynik =  pg_query($q) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne 1:".$q);  
$arr = pg_fetch_array($wynik);

 echo"
 <div class='span9'>

 <table class=\"table\"> 
 <thead>
            <tr> 
                   <th>Playlista : "; echo pobierz_nazwe_playlisty($edytuj); echo" </th> 

            </tr>
            <tr>
     <th >Nazwa pliku viedo</th>

     <th >Czas pliku video</th>

     <th >Rozmiar</th>

     <th >Ilość odtworzeń</th>

     <th >Ostatnio grany</th>

     <th >Operacja</th>
            </tr> ";           

$prevrank=0;
$previd=0;
$nextrank=0;
$nextid=0;

foreach ($arr as $key=>$r) {
 if($key > 0) {
     $prevrank = $arr[$key - 1]['pozycja'];
     $previd = $arr[$key - 1]['id'];
 }

 if($key < pg_num_rows($wynik)) {
     $nextrank = $arr[$key + 1]['pozycja'];
     $nextid = $arr[$key + 1]['id'];
 }

    echo"   <tr class=\"tab_nag3\">"; 

     echo "<td > {$r['nazwa']} </td> ";

     echo "       <td > ".milisekundynaminuty($r['czas'])." </td> ";

     echo "       <td >" ; echo bajtynamegabajty($r['rozmiar']); echo" </td> ";

       echo "     <td > {$r['ilosc_odtworzen']} </td> ";

        echo "    <td >".zmiana_daty($r['ostatnio_grana'])." </td>   ";

       echo "<td ><a href=\"playlista_video.php?usun_zplaylisty={$r['id']}&edytuj=$edytuj&typ=$typ\">Usuń</a></td><td>";
  if($key > 0 ) {   
  // If you are number one you cannot go higher.
      echo "<a href=\"playlista_video.php?\id={$r['id']}&previd=$previd&newpos=$prevrank&currank={$r['pozycja']}&action=plus\"><button>+</button></a>";
  }

  // If you are last you cannot go lower!
  if($key < pg_num_rows($wynik)) {
       echo "<a href=\"playlista_video.php?\id={$r['id']}&nextid=$nextid&newpos=$nextrank&currank={$r['pozycja']}&action=minus\"><button>-</button></a>";
  }
      echo "</td></tr> "   

    ;
  }

echo"</table>    

  ";
  echo '<a href="okno_video.php?opcja=2&id_playlisty='.$edytuj.'&typ='.$typ.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active pull-right" role="button ">Dodaj nowe zasoby</a>';

  include  ('stopka.php');
  echo '</div>';

?>
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have something like a rank field in your table? Try and describe the data and the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

add position field to your database, it its not exists, and fill it by default with auto_incremented field value. Then you should have two buttons: Up and Down.
On Up button click, just get value of nearest bigger item, and switch that value with button clicked item's fields value.

Then you must add ORDER BY that position field in your database request to correctly show your ordered items.

Answer (score 0):

Include the pozycja field in the results of you query.
When you start your loop save the previous rank in a variable except for the first one.

Try this solution but **PLEASE STUDY IT BEFORE APPLYING AS I HAVE WRITTEN IT WITHOUT TESTING AND I DO NOT WANT TO STUFF UP YOUR DATA!!**

You can see that you have to change the logic with which you loop through the results. I have used an array as I find it very easy and you can access directly the columns with their names. Also you have a key with which you can access previous and next results so that you can generate the update queries to swap the rank (pozycja) values of the songs.

This is the easiest solution but i do not find it elegant as you have to reload the page every time. If you want a suggestion I would recode using jquery and ajax calls to achieve this but it will need some study.

```
// Update the database exchanging the positions
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "plus") {
    pg_query($con, "update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['prevrank'] . "where id=" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "; update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['currank'] . "where    id=" . $_REQUEST['previd']);
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "minus") {
    pg_query($con, "update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['nextrank'] .     "where id=" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "; update zasobyplaylisty set pozycja=" . $_REQUEST['currank'] . "where    id=" . $_REQUEST['nextid']);
}


$q = " SELECT z.id, id_playlisty, id_melodii, ilosc_odtworzen, ostatnio_grana, nazwa, rozmiar, czas, pozcyja from zasobyplaylisty z LEFT JOIN melodie m ON z.id_melodii=m.id WHERE id_playlisty=$edytuj ORDER BY pozycja";

$wynik =  pg_query($q) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne 1:".$q);  
$arr = pg_fetch_array($wynik);

 echo"
 <div class='span9'>

 <table class=\"table\"> 
 <thead>

            <tr> 

                   <th>Playlista : "; echo pobierz_nazwe_playlisty($edytuj); echo" </th> 

            </tr>

            <tr>

     <th >Nazwa pliku viedo</th>

     <th >Czas pliku video</th>

     <th >Rozmiar</th>

     <th >Ilość odtworzeń</th>

     <th >Ostatnio grany</th>

     <th >Operacja</th>

            </tr>
       ";           

$prevrank=0;
$previd=0;
$nextrank=0;
$nextid=0;


foreach ($arr as $key=>$r) {
 if($key > 0) {
     $prevrank = $arr[$key - 1]['pozycja'];
     $previd = $arr[$key - 1]['id'];
 }

 if($key < pg_num_rows($wynik)) {
     $nextrank = $arr[$key + 1]['pozycja'];
     $nextid = $arr[$key + 1]['id'];
 }

    echo"   <tr class=\"tab_nag3\">

            <td > $r['nazwa'] </td>

            <td > ".milisekundynaminuty($r['czas'])." </td>

            <td >"; echo bajtynamegabajty($r['rozmiar']); echo" </td> 

            <td > $r['ilosc_odtworzen'] </td>

            <td >".zmiana_daty($r['ostatnio_grana'])." </td>     

            <td >

                <a href=\"playlista_video.php?usun_zplaylisty=$r['id']&edytuj=$edytuj&typ=$typ\">Usuń</a></td><td>";
  if($key > 0 ) {   
  // If you are number one you cannot go higher.
      echo "<a href=\"playlista_video.php?\id=$r['id']&previd=$previd&newpos=$prevrank&currank=$r['pozycjya']&action=plus"><button>+</button></a>";
  }

  // If you are last you cannot go lower!
  if($key < pg_num_rows($wynik)) {
       echo "<a href=\"playlista_video.php?\id=$r['id']&nextid=$nextid&newpos=$nextrank&currank=$r['pozycjya']&action=minus"><button>-</button></a>";
  }
      echo "</td></tr>    

    ";
  }
```

Comment: Also column "pozycja" in postgresql has "nextval('zasobyplaylisty_pozycja_seq'::regclass)" definition